# Dialog automatically continue when user closes or press a button in the webview on Botframework V4

Tags: c#, facebook, botframework, facebook-messenger, messenger

I have a web app deployed in azure that opens in Messenger Webview. I made a empty text prompt for user to click for the user to be able to continue when they close the Webview. However, users sometimes forget to click the button. I read [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webview/#close) doc but i can't manage to do it as i learn best seeing actual examples and codes. How can the dialog automatically continue when the user closes or press a button in the Webview? Thank you.

The web view is a set of questions and the answer of the users are save in Cosmos DB and when they close the web view the bot access their scores in Cosmos DB and calculate their scores.

This is my current code.

```
private static async Task<DialogTurnResult> ThirdStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
{
    Activity reply = stepContext.Context.Activity.CreateReply();
    reply.ChannelData = JObject.FromObject(
        new
        {
            attachment = new
            {
                type = "template",
                payload = new
                {
                    template_type = "generic",
                    elements = new[]
                    {
                          new
                          {
                                title = "<title>",
                                buttons = new object[]
                                {
                                new
                                   {
                                        type = "web_url",
                                        title = "<title>",
                                        url = webAppUrl,
                                        messenger_extensions="true",
                                        webview_height_ratio = "tall",
                                   },
                                new
                                   {
                                        type = "postback",
                                        title = "Done ✔️",
                                        payload = "Done ✔️",
                                   },
                                },
                          },
                    },
                },
            },
        });
    await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(reply);

    return await stepContext.PromptAsync(
        nameof(TextPrompt),
        new PromptOptions
        {
            Prompt = MessageFactory.Text(string.Empty),
            RetryPrompt = MessageFactory.Text("Click Done to proceed."),
        });
}

private static async Task<DialogTurnResult> FourthStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var result = stepContext.Result.ToString().ToLower();

    if (result == "done ✔️" || result == "done")
    {
        return await stepContext.NextAsync();
    }

    await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(
            MessageFactory.Text(
                $"Please press done to proceed, thank you!"));

    return await stepContext.ReplaceDialogAsync(nameof(CalendarIncomeExpensesDialogV2));
}
```

update rafa:
[image]

Comment: You linked to a document that explains how to close a webview programmatically, but your question seems to be asking how to subscribe to a webhook that gets triggered when the user closes the webview manually. Do you understand the difference?

Comment: @KyleDelaney Yes Sir sorry i realized that too just moments ago thank you for correcting. I will remove the document.

Comment: Removing the document doesn't help. You need to provide more info, not less. At any rate, it doesn't look like Facebook webviews provide a webhook for when they close. Would you be satisfied with an alternative solution? Perhaps there's a way to design the flow of your dialog so that you don't need to know when the user closes the webview. Can you explain what the webview is supposed to do?

Comment: @KyleDelaney Yes sir Kyle i will be satisfied with an alternative. But i saw some bots with that feature that when you close a web view the dialog automatically continues, But anyways the web view is a set of questions and the answer of the users are save in Cosmos DB and when they close the web view the bot access their scores in Cosmos DB and calculate their scores.

Comment: Can you link to the bots where you've seen that behavior?

Comment: @KyleDelaney https://www.messenger.com/t/TalktoRafa Here sir . when you choose "Car loans" and "start with my budget" and "Ok"

Comment: I can't view TalktoRafa so I presume it isn't available in the US, but perhaps you can describe the behavior to me a bit more. Is the webview closing itself in response to you clicking on a button inside the webview? Is there a way to close the webview without clicking OK, like by pressing esc or something?

Comment: Sure sir. The webview opens and theres the normal "X" on the upper right and a "submit" button. when you press X the webview closes but nothing happens. When you press ESC nothing happens, when you press submit button the webview closes and the dialog automatically continues

Comment: You say that nothing happens when you press X to close the webview. That means there's no indication that the bot receives an event when the user closes the webview. The bot only responds when the user clicks a button in the webview, which means the button is programmed to send a message to the bot. The bot is responding to the message that the button sends it and is not responding to the webview closing.

Comment: I see. Is there a sample of that anywhere Sir Kyle? What are the steps needed to do that?

Comment: That depends entirely on how you've made the app in your webview. If you'd like help with that app then you'll have to post the code and provide screenshots. You could send an HTTP request directly to your bot's endpoint or you could go through the Azure Bot Service using the callback URL and verify token.

Comment: Are you still working on this?

Comment: Yes sir kyle. Sorry i had a problem migrating my codes to the latest version but its okay now.

Comment: I updated the question with pic of rafa chat. I don't know where to start though, how did rafa do it. does the webapp send a proactive message to the bot? my webview is in the middle of a dialog so what i need is a trigger to continue. but how i can't think of a way for the bot to wait for a trigger then continue.

Comment: I am fairly certain the web app must send a proactive message to the bot. Do you need help understanding how to get a web app to do this? Or are you just asking how to have the bot respond to such a message?

Comment: Both sir if possible, Right now i dont have idea for the webapp but for the bot to respond im thinking of assigning the proactive message of the webapp to a LUIS intent. I have an InterruptionDialog class that has dialogs opening when a certain text or luis intent is matched, I based in on the HelpAndCancel interruption on the core sample. but now instead of continuing i will open a new dialog. Or is there a better approach here sir kyle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you don't even know what kind of web app you're trying to create or what language you're writing the web app in or how you plan on hosting the web app, your first step is to figure all that out. If you need help with any part of that process then you'll need to ask a new very specific question about it and include what you've tried so far along with all the relevant code.

When you open the web app in your Facebook webview, you'll need to make sure the web app has all the information it needs to send an activity to the bot (I've been calling it a proactive message but those normally refer to bot-to-user messages). The needed credentials should already be built into the web app, so the only thing you'll need to send to the web app's endpoint is the user ID so that the web app can pass it along in the activity and the bot can identify which conversation the activity pertains to. The conventional way to send an activity to the bot is using Direct Line, though you may figure out a way to do it by just sending an HTTP request to the bot's endpoint or even using your Facebook app's callback URL.

There is absolutely no need to involve LUIS in this. LUIS should only be used to interpret messages from the user when you don't know what the user will say. Any time you're in control of the message that's getting sent to the bot, it doesn't make any sense to use LUIS. Keep in mind that there are 15+ activity types and your activity doesn't need to be a "message" activity. There are many ways you can identify the activity and respond accordingly in your bot. I recommend using an event activity.

Based on my understanding of your proficiency level, you will likely need to do a lot of research to accomplish what you're trying to accomplish. The documentation is a great place to start: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/

Comment: Thank you! I will do more research on this. Just want to confirm 1 thing sir, If i want to replicate that in rafa bot. The dialog should end with the webview button being shown. and when the web app send a message to the bot that is a start of another dialog? Because i think there is no way to wait for a trigger mid-dialog right?

Comment: @user10860402 - There is absolutely a way to wait for a trigger mid-dialog. If you use a custom prompt, perhaps an `ActivityPrompt`, you can keep reprompting until the desired event activity is received. This may be undesirable of course, because what if the user closes the webview with the close button instead of the submit button? You may want to allow the dialog to continue without receiving the special event activity.